# Active admin rails action button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am very new to active admin and  using below form

```
active_admin_form_for resource, :url => account_setup_admin_customer_path(resource), :method => :post,  :html => {:class => "new_meeting_search", :id => "meeting_search"} do |f|
  f.inputs "Customer Details" do
    h2 "Customer Name: #{resource.first_name} #{resource.last_name}"
    h2 "Company: #{resource.company_name}"
    h2 "Email: #{resource.email}"
    f.input :bill_to
    f.input :ship_to
    f.input :primary_dc, :as => :select, :collection => [["CI - Chambersburg, PA", "CI - Chambersburg, PA"], ["DD - Fort Wayne, IN", "DD - Fort Wayne, IN"], ["EE - Roseburg, OR", "EE - Roseburg, OR"], ["NV - La Vergne, TN", "NV - La Vergne, TN"]]
    f.input :secondary_dc, :as => :select, :collection => [["CI - Chambersburg, PA", "CI - Chambersburg, PA"], ["DD - Fort Wayne, IN", "DD - Fort Wayne, IN"], ["EE - Roseburg, OR", "EE - Roseburg, OR"], ["NV - La Vergne, TN", "NV - La Vergne, TN"]]
    f.input :ips_primary_dc, :as => :select, :collection => [["CI - Chambersburg, PA", "CI - Chambersburg, PA"], ["DD - Fort Wayne, IN", "DD - Fort Wayne, IN"], ["EE - Roseburg, OR", "EE - Roseburg, OR"], ["NV - La Vergne, TN", "NV - La Vergne, TN"]]
    f.input :ips_secondary_dc, :as => :select, :collection => [["CI - Chambersburg, PA", "CI - Chambersburg, PA"], ["DD - Fort Wayne, IN", "DD - Fort Wayne, IN"], ["EE - Roseburg, OR", "EE - Roseburg, OR"], ["NV - La Vergne, TN", "NV - La Vergne, TN"]]
    f.input :ipi_account_number
    f.input :ipage_username
    f.input :ipage_password
    f.input :status, :as => :select, :collection => [["Approved", "Approved"], ["Denied", "Denied"]]
    f.input :status_comment
  end
  f.actions
end
```

Instead of status dropdown, I want separate action buttons "Approve", "Deny","Cancel" . I am not sure how to add custom buttons in active form.

Comment: please let me know if my nswer was helpful

Comment: Hi...Sorry Andrey....I didn't login after posting my question...managed to get it working...Thanks for your help...Your way is better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do so you will need to use `member_action`.

First, in your model create a public methods:

```
model MyModel
  #... 
  def approve
    #... any logic here, for example:
    update(status: 'Approved')
  end
end
```

Then, in AA page you'll do:

```
  action_item only: [:edit] do # or any page, where you need this button
    link_to('Approve', the_path_to_aprove(resource), method: :post
  end


  member_action :approve, method: :post do
      if resource.approve
        redirect_to somewhere_path, notice: "This have been approved!"
      else
        redirect_to somewhere_else_path, alert: "Sorry, not all requirements were met for approving"
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put 3 links to simulate. more details you can refer to the AA's form customizing [document](http://activeadmin.info/docs/5-forms.html).